# Coldfusion - Avoid IIS 404.0 error for specific files and do manual routing instead

Tags: iis, coldfusion, routes, http-status-code-404, coldfusion-10

I am using coldfusion 10 and iis 7.5 and trying to create a custom routing for my project that avoids using query string.

For example, the following URL:

> www.myTestWebsite.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/

should be passing from a router.cfm file that exists in the root folder and then based on the string after the website's domain (in this case /subfolder1/subfolder2/) coldfusion will decide what to show and how.

I managed to make everything work except for one thing. If index.cfm (or .html, or any default file) does not exist in the /subfolder1/subfolder2/ path, IIS shows a 404.0 error. However, if create the folder structure and add an empty index.cfm file there, the routing works as expected, ignoring that empty index.cfm and moving on according to the logic I have implemented.

Is there a way (through CF Administrator, IIS, htaccess or any other) to avoid checking if that file exists and throwing a 404.0 and instead allowing me to handle that through my route.cfm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use rewriting in web.config:

```
<rule name="wvcms" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/route.cfm?cmspath=/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Note: This requires that the IIS URL Rewrite extension be installed (https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).  Using URL Rewrite feature is probably the easiest way to solve this problem.

Comment: Something like this worked. The key is URL Rewrite extension.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a custom ColdFusion servlet mapping. The information below comes from the Taffy ColdFusion REST API framework documentation.
http://docs.taffy.io/3.1.0#404-when-your-api-is-in-a-subdirectory

In your web.xml, you need to add an additional servlet mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>CFMLServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/api/index.cfm/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is because Tomcat doesn't support the use of two wildcards in its mappings. You'll notice that installing ACF or Lucee in Tomcat you'll get a web.xml with mappings that have a url-pattern of index.cfm/*, but unfortunately because of this limitation, you can't change that to */index.cfm/*.

In the xml above you can see that I only have 1 wildcard, but to compensate I've specified the entire path to index.cfm, so that only 1 is needed. (Note that I used /api/index.cfm because it matched my example of a 404 for /api/index.cfm/myResource... yours should match the location of your index.cfm).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kevin. I should have made it clear that I am totally new in this area so most of the answers (yours included) are most likely going to sound strange to my ears. Could we utilize a chat functionality to talk about it in real time?

Comment: You're welcome for the answer. I hope that it helps solve your problem.
The purpose of the Stack Exchange sites is to foster community based on shared, visible and transparent community participation to help posters solve issues. If you have more questions, it would be best to post them publicly on Stack Overflow so that the conversation and answers can be shared.

Comment: P.S. If my answer worked to solve your problem, please remember to mark it as "accepted". Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I had no luck with the servlet mapping. I had to add the following code in my web.config to make my specs possible:
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1">
 <match url="^(.+)$" />
                    <conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="/subfolderName/index.cfm?{R:1}" />
</rule>